# Veracrypt with /etc/udev/rules.d

Tags: ubuntu, bash, debian, mount, veracrypt

Consider that I have `/etc/udev/rules.d/91-checkveracrypt.rules`:

```
ACTION=="add", ATTRS{idVendor}=="1234", ATTRS{idProduct}=="1234", RUN+="/home/user/tryveracrypt.sh"
```

`/home/user/tryveracrypt.sh`:

```
reqsubstr="/dev/disk/by-id/usb-AAAAA-0:0-part1"
for word in $DEVLINKS
do
  if [ "$word" == "$reqsubstr" ] ; then
     /usr/bin/su user -c '/bin/bash /home/user/mountveracrypt.sh'
     exit
  fi
done
```

And finally `mountveracrypt.sh`:

```
sudo veracrypt -t -k /home/user/key -p "" --pim=0 --protect-hidden=no /dev/disk/by-id/usb-AAAAA-0:0-part1 --slot=1 --verbose --non-interactive > /tmp/mount 2>&1
```

`/usr/bin/veracrypt` is in `/etc/sudoers` so veracrypt doesn't ask for password. Calling `./mountveracrypt.sh` as user works fine. I understand `tryveracrypt.sh` is run as root, so I'm calling `mountveracrypt.sh` with `su user` so the mount is available to user.

If I try:

```
sudo su
./mountveracrypt.sh
exit (go back to user)
veracrypt -t -l
```

I get:

```
Error: No volumes mounted.
```

But `sudo veracrypt -t -l` gets:

```
1: /dev/disk/by-id/usb-AAAAA-0:0-part1 /dev/mapper/veracrypt1 /media/veracrypt1
```

**Ok. Fine. Mounting as root, the volume is only available to root. What is annoying me is when I plug the USB and it runs `/udev/rules.d/` script.**

`cat /tmp/mount`:

```
Volume "/dev/disk/by-id/usb-AAAAA-0:0-part1" has been mounted.
```

`veracrypt -t -l`:

```
Error: No volumes mounted.
```

`sudo veracrypt -t -l`:

```
Error: No volumes mounted.
```

**Why?? I can't access mount as user, not even as root. What am I missing?**

EDIT:

I can't dismount the volume with `veracrypt -d` because veracrypt doesn't see it. I need to reboot the system to unplug.

Does udev/rules run in a different user than root? Although I used `whoami` and it shows root, and `su user -c 'whoami'` shows user as expected.

Also, I made a script in udev/rules to mount veracrypt, copy some files and dismount, and it works fine. I just can't access files and dismount veracrypt outside the script called from udev/rules.

Comment: Some ideas. 1. Does veracrypt supports access permissions in /etc/fstab? Perhaps you can archieve desired user permissions without running as root/sudo -c problems. 2. Does veracrypt support on-demand mounting via fstab with 'nofail' option? I use other encryption software, I manually call systemctl start mount point (with user permissions) when I plug external drive. Perhaps you can setup so user can manually mount and then add 'systemctl start mount_pount.mnt' in udev script.

Comment: I never set fstab configs with veracrypt or use it with `--fs-options`, but I'll try your ideas. It's still annoying because I can't dismount the volume with `veracrypt -d` because veracrypt doesn't see it. I need to reboot the system to unplug.